# Express partial derivatives sum which isn't a gradient or a divergence

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

I want to simplify the following formula (heat transfer context) :

$$f(\vec{v}, T) = v_x \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} + v_y \frac{\partial T}{\partial y}  + v_z \frac{\partial T}{\partial z}$$

I'm very tempted to write:

$$f(\vec{v}, T) = \nabla (vT)$$
Yet, I believe this isn't thorough enough. Indeed:

$$\vec{div}(f) : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 : f(x,y,z) \mapsto  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vec{1}_x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vec{1}_y  + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\vec{1}_z$$

$$grad(\vec f) : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : (f_x, f_y, f_z) \mapsto  \frac{\partial f_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f_y}{\partial z}$$

The temperature $T(x, y, z)$ is scalar, but I want $f(\vec{v}, T)$ to be a scalar too. So my "$\nabla$" would be neither a gradient nor a divergence. Do you have an idea of what I can write ?

---

**EDIT**:

This comes from the following equation:

[image: the equation]

Comment: What would you do if we re-write  $f(\vec{v}, T) = f(\vec{H})$ where  $\vec{H} = \vec{(x,y,z,t)}$

Comment: This allows us to use the gradient on $f(\vec H)$, but I don't see how I could find a direct link between $\vec v$ and $T$ to express everything with respect to $\vec H$

Comment: It's just $\vec{v} \cdot \nabla T$ (scalar product), isn't it?

Comment: Before I dissect the formulas you are tempted to write. What does the formula you want to simplify mean? The right hand side does not seem to depend on $f$.

Comment: (By the way, your formulas for div and grad don't make much sense!)

Comment: @HansLundmark it is from the global heat balance considering conduction and advection, $f(\vec v, T) = k\Delta T/(\rho c_p)$

Comment: $\boldsymbol v\cdot \nabla$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you want ? I am not sure.
$$f(\vec{v}, T) = v_x \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} + v_y \frac{\partial T}{\partial y}  + v_z \frac{\partial T}{\partial z}$$
I suppose that your notation $v_x$ doesn't means $\frac{\partial v(x,y,z)}{\partial x}$.

In order to avoid confusion I change of notation such as $v_x\equiv v_1$ :
$$\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
v_3\end{bmatrix}$$
and vector gradiant :
$$\vec{grad(T)}=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}\end{bmatrix}$$
Dot product of vectors :
$$\boxed{v_1 \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} + v_2 \frac{\partial T}{\partial y}  + v_3 \frac{\partial T}{\partial z}=\vec{v}\:.\:\vec{grad(T)}}$$